# How to sync time if ntp was block centos

Tags: centos

How do i able to sync time when ntp is block from isp?

One of the way i try is link the /usr/share/zoneinfo to /etc/localtime

However , it is not the correct way of doing it.

Please advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Setup Timing ( Without NTP) CentOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127701/how-to-setup-timing-without-ntp-centos)

Comment: Please don't post [essentially the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127701) multiple times.

Comment: ok i have deleted that post.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Actually the link you posted is deleted.